# Align text to the left in Forest tree

Tags: forest

An MWE is provided below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    forked edges,for tree={grow'=0}
        [{Sino-Tibetan}
            [{Chinese [Sinitic]}]
            [{Tibeto-Burman}
                [{Lolo-Burmese}]
                [{Bodish}
                    [{Tibetan}]
                    [{……}]
                ]
                [{Qiangic}
                    [{Qiang}]
                    [{Rgyalrongic}]
                    [{Pumi and Ersuic}]
                    [{Naish (Naxi)}]
                ]
                [{……}]
            ]
        ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

**The output** is:
[image]

**What I desire** is to align every item in the same level **to the left**, like:
[image]

Plz tell me the simplest solution. Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,for tree={grow'=0,align=left,anchor=west}
        [{Sino-Tibetan}
            [{Chinese [Sinitic]}]
            [{Tibeto-Burman}
                [{Lolo-Burmese}]
                [{Bodish}
                    [{Tibetan}]
                    [{\dots}]
                ]
                [{Qiangic}
                    [{Qiang}]
                    [{Rgyalrongic}]
                    [{Pumi and Ersuic}]
                    [{Naish (Naxi)}]
                ]
                [{\dots}]
            ]
        ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]